# Updating system for deployed Windows application C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clickonce, updates

I'm using CickOnce deployment Technique for build the Updating system for a kiosk machine winform application.But want to know is there other methods to do it

Comment: i would strongly recommend using a **pull** approach rather than **push** (deployed installer) if you have a high number of clients.  so the client on a regular basis reaches out to the server to see if there are updates to install and if so has the ability to self update or notify to a human to run an update

Comment: You might be interested in [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) which allows for things like rollbacks, staged rollouts, no admin updates and a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with ClickOnce is when something goes wrong, it does not store previous versions side by side. If the new version is buggy then your app stops working until you release another version that then must be downloaded.

Instead I recommend you create your own bootstrapper. A small program that runs and automatically contacts your server to check for and download any new version. Not dissimilar to the ClickOnce process, except yours will store the last few versions side by side. That way your server can return a value indicating which version to run and so all the clients can be reverted to a recent version very quickly without downloading it again.

Because it is your own bootstrapper you can extend it as well. Add the ability to tell the application to refuse to run until the server says so. You could do this per-install or globally to all clients. (Handy if you customer does not pay the bill!)